# An additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$ is dense on a subspace if $0$ is a limit point of it

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R^n,+)$. If $0$ is a limit point of $A$, is it true that there exists a non-zero vector subspace $V$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $A\cap V$ is dense on $V$?

Comment: What did you try to prove it? Did you try at least the 1-dimensional case?

Comment: @MoisheKohan The 1d case is easy. For any small interval $(x,x+\varepsilon)$, we can pick $a\in A$ with $0<|a|<\varepsilon$, and then the group generated by $\{a\}$ must have an element in the said interval. Then, $A$ is dense on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I think you can find such a subspace by considering the quantity $m_\epsilon$ which is "the maximum size of a linearly independent set in $B_\epsilon(0) \cap A$", as $\epsilon \to 0$. Argue that $m_\epsilon$ tends to some limit $m > 0$, and for sufficiently small $\epsilon$ (so this limit is attained), any set of $m$ linearly independent vectors in $B_\epsilon(0) \cap A$ generates the same subspace $V$. Then argue that since $A \cap V$ contains arbitrarily-small-in-magnitude generating sets for $V$, it's dense in $V$...

Comment: Let $V$ be the smallest subspace containing $A$. If $N$ is a neighborhood of some point $v\in V$, then $N - v = \{w - v : w\in N\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$. Apply the same logic as you did in the 1D case.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I'm not sure that's right. For example, in $\Bbb R^2$, the subgroup $A = \Bbb Q \times \Bbb Z$ generates the whole space, but it's not dense in the whole space, right? I think this is why some argument about $V$ being the smallest subspace which contains $B_\epsilon(0) \cap A$ for very small $\epsilon$ is needed.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen - I interpreted the claim "$A$ is dense on $V$" to mean that $A$ is a dense subset of $V$, and therefore for your example $V$ would be the entirety of $\Bbb R^2$. And your example would prove the claim false. But it looks like you are interpreting the phrase to mean that $A\cap V$ is a dense subset of $V$, which is a different matter. Perhaps your interpretation is the one intended. In which case $V$ would be the span of $A\cap N$ for some neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh I see the ambiguity. I need to slightly edit my question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I definitely am not interested in the trivial answer, but I edited the question.